# AutocompleteArrayInput displays blank entries

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I have an array in my database which I would like to CRUD using react-admin. The [AutocompleteArrayInput](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#autocompletearrayinput) component meets my needs in every way but one. The problem I am experiencing is that AutocompleteArrayInput does not display entries which are not from the finite list of options provided to the component. If an entry is not present in the list of options, react-admin does not display the custom text which was inserted and instead shows no text instead, like so:

[image: blank entries in AutocompleteArrayInput]

**Consider the following example:**

```
Which colors do you like? Select all that apply

- Red
- Blue
- Green
- Other (write in your own)
```

Example arrays include:

- ["Red"]
- ["Red", "Green"]
- ["Pink"]
- ["Maroon"]

I pass the array of ["Red", "Blue", "Green"] to AutocompleteArrayInput in react-admin. The first two examples display fine, because both "Red" and "Green" are in the known list. However, the problem is that react-admin does not display the text of "Pink" or "Maroon," and instead shows an empty entry instead.

Is there a setting to change in order to have react-admin display the raw input text instead of just displaying blank?

**Sample code:**

```
const my_choices = [
  {id:'red', name:'red'},
  {id:'green', name:'green'},
  {id:'blue', name:'blue'}
];

export const ResourceEdit = (props) => (
  <Edit {...props} redirect="list">
      <SimpleForm>
          <AutocompleteArrayInput source="Colors" choices = {my_choices} allowEmpty />
      </SimpleForm>
 </Edit>
);
```

For the above example, I would like autocomplete for `red`, `green`, and `blue`, but if another color is present in the array, I want to be able to see it in the admin interface, too, and not just have it show up as blank.

Am I missing a configuration setting? I want to avoid providing an exhaustive list of options to the component, if possible.

**Environment**

- React-admin version: 2.9.2
- Last version that did not exhibit the issue (if applicable): Unknown
- React version: 16.8.6
- Browser: Tested on Chrome and Firefox

Comment: The only solution would be to write a custom component that wraps <AutocompleteArrayInput> IMO

Answer (score 0):

Add the property optionText.

```
const choices = [
    { _id: 123, full_name: 'Leo Tolstoi', sex: 'M' },
    { _id: 456, full_name: 'Jane Austen', sex: 'F' },
];

<AutocompleteArrayInput source="author_id" choices={choices} optionText="full_name" optionValue="_id" />
```

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Inputs.html#autocompletearrayinput

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - turns out I was using a `ReferenceInput` when I should've been using a `ReferenceArrayInput`.

i.e.

```xml
<ReferenceInput
    ...
>
    <AutocompleteArrayInput
        ...
    />
</ReferenceInput>
```

... should've been...

```xml
<ReferenceArrayInput
    ...
>
    <AutocompleteArrayInput
        ...
    />
</ReferenceArrayInput>
```